# Bounce Dismissible for helping the user

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So we have a Dismissible for confirming/denying a item.
However we have some users that are trying to click/tap on the item.
Our UX team suggested that we then "bounce" the item to show that they have to swipe (and reveal the action fields).
But I don't see any option to do so.

Does anybody have a suggestion what might work for this?
The code I have for now is shown below:

```dart
Dismissible(
  key: const ValueKey(0),
  direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
  child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3, vertical: 3),
    child: card(),
  ),
  confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
    var newStatus = direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd
        ? OkNokNvt.OK
        : OkNokNvt.NOK;

    _changeStatus(newStatus);
    return false;
  },
  background: ok(),
  secondaryBackground: nok(),
),
```

Comment: You can wrap the `Container` with an `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` widget which have the `onTap` property you are looking for. In the `onTap` callback you can then trigger a bounce animation

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I think those options don't reveal the background? but will just bounce the item, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dismissable` doesn't seeem to have this functionality.

Instead, you could use the [flutter_slidable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) package.

Here, you can programmatically open the underlying actions by calling `Slideable.of(context)?.open()`. No fancy bounce-animation though.

[image: dismissable widget]

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bouncing Widget Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Slidable(
              key: const Key('key'),
              actionPane: const SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
              actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
              child: Builder(
                builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Slidable.of(context)
                        ?.open(actionType: SlideActionType.primary);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: 50,
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Tap me')),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: 'Delete',
                  color: Colors.red,
                  icon: Icons.delete,
                  onTap: () => print('remove me from list'),
                ),
              ],
              dismissal: SlidableDismissal(
                onDismissed: (_) => print('remove me from list'),
                dragDismissible: true,
                child: const SlidableDrawerDismissal(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think I can make it work with your example (or get close enough) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my minimal example which does what you are looking for.

[image: bouncing widget example gif]

Basically, the `GestureDetector` `onTap` callback triggers the animation which has a bouncing-like effect by using a `sin` function on the `_animation.value`. The behaviour can be tweeked by changing the parameters `cyclesPerAnimation` and `bounceOffset`.

Simply put your `Dismissible` in the place of the `Container` and you should be good to go.

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _animation = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  );

  Offset _bounceOffset(double animationValue) {
    const cyclesPerAnimation = 2;
    const bounceOffset = 10;
    return Offset(
      0,
      sin(animationValue * pi * 2 * cyclesPerAnimation) * bounceOffset,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bouncing Widget Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _animation,
              builder: (context, widget) => Transform.translate(
                offset: _bounceOffset(_animation.value),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    _animation.reset();
                    _animation.forward();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    height: 50,
                    width: 200,
                    child: const Center(child: Text('Tap to bounce')),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think this option doesn't reveal the background? but will just bounce the item, correct?

Comment: you mean the item has to bounce horizontally, so you see the underlying action fields? Maybe some screenshots of your Dismissible would be helpful

Comment: yeah exactly I want to show the user that there are action fields